# Converting subquery to fetch MAX value to join in Hive

Tags: sql, hive

I am trying to convert a presto query to Hive query which will fetch max value from a subquery. The below query doesn't seem to be supported in Hive.

```
select a.id, b.acct_id
from table_a a
inner join table_b b
on etl_state='current'
and load_date=(select max(load_date) from table_a)
and a.acct_id = b.acct_id
```

Error while running above query in Hive:

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.optimizer.calcite.CalciteSubquerySemanticException: 0:0 Unsupported SubQuery Expression Currently SubQuery expressions are only allowed as Where and Having Clause predicates. Error encountered near token 'load_date'
```

Please advise what I can modify to have the above query Hive compatible.

Comment: Which error do you get when you run the query in hive exactly? Sample data and desired results would also help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have added the error that I am getting to the original post. There is no sample data. I am trying to convert Presto SQL to Hive SQL

Answer (score 0):

This kind of subquery doesnt work in hive. You need to convert it to a inner join.
Pls use this.

```
select a.id, b.acct_id
from table_a a
inner join table_b b on etl_state='current' 
Inner Join (select max(load_date) mx from table_a) mxdt on load_date=mxdt.mx
and a.acct_id = b.acct_id
```